# using regex finding a pattern in a sentence in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

hi I have sample dataframe like below

```
    col
0   [This is a sample, I have a string]
1   [sample question, strings are immutable]
2   [cool weather, It is hot]
```

using regex I want to find out whether "sample" or "string" present in the sentence , if present return the whole text in new column, if not return None to the new column.

```
    col                                       Text
0   [This is a sample, I have a string]       [This is a sample, I have a string]
1   [sample question, strings are immutable]  [sample question, strings are immutable]
2   [cool weather, It is hot]                 None
```

Could you help me find out the correct solution for this?

Comment: Hi! Did your query solved? if so then try considering [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so that the answer can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 0):

Try via `contains()`:

```
m=df['col'].str.contains('sample|string')
df.loc[m,'Text']=df.loc[m,'col']
```

OR

If the values inside 'col' columns is of type list then you can use:

```
m=df['col'].map(lambda x:any(y for y in x for z in ['sample','string'] if z in y))
df.loc[m,'Text']=df.loc[m,'col']
#OR
m=df['col'].astype(str).str.contains('sample|string')
df.loc[m,'Text']=df.loc[m,'col']
```

output of `df`:

```
    col                                         Text
0   [This is a sample, I have a string]         [This is a sample, I have a string]
1   [sample question, strings are immutable]    [sample question, strings are immutable]
2   [cool weather, It is hot]                   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort..any other ways without using "contains" or "any" @Anurag Dabas

Comment: @Cherry I don't think so that there is another way

Comment: @Cherry these 2 are straight forward methods